# Macbook trackpad driver

Tags: touchpad, drivers, macbook

I'm running elementary OS on a 2011 Macbook pro. I'm quite pleased with the overall experience but the trackpad feel is quite a disappointment (too sensitive, not precise, issues with selection/drag&drop/scrolling etc.).

My question is: is there an ideal configuration to make it work in a satisfying way? Which driver behaves best? I heard there's synaptics, libinput, mtrack... but I'm no expert.

Comment: there's no driver or device that can even compete with the macbook touchpad, and that driver is only avaiable in macOS so you will never experience the same thing, but you can try libinput (`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput`) just make sure that libinput driver is the only installed on your system because otherwise the system will crash, don't use synaptics is no longer supported in linux and it might crash (synaptics driver aren't updated since 2012)

Comment: Thanks, Renato. So your recommendation is to use libinput over synaptics...yet the latter is still default, right? Any tip on how to make the transition as painless as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I simply ran these commands and it works pretty well!  Nothing else was needed.

Go root first by executing `sudo -i` or `sudo su` in the terminal and then execute the commands bellow,

```
echo -e "\n# applespi\napplespi\nspi_pxa2xx_platform\nspi_pxa2xx_pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
apt install dkms git
git clone https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver.git /usr/src/applespi-0.1
dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
shutdown -r now
```